# Turn JSON data containing ee entries into map markers

Tags: google-maps, json

This is the json data

```
{ 
  "title": "{exp:channel:entries channel="supplier_branches" orderby="title" sort="asc" dynamic="no" limit="500" status="open"}{title}{/exp:channel:entries}",
  "info": "infoz",
  "lat": "{exp:channel:entries channel="supplier_branches" orderby="title" sort="asc" dynamic="no" limit="500" status="open"}{sb_lat}{/exp:channel:entries}",
  "lng": "{exp:channel:entries channel="supplier_branches" orderby="title" sort="asc" dynamic="no" limit="500" status="open"}{sb_lng}{/exp:channel:entries}"
}
```

This is the code to get markers:

```
function setMarkers(center, map) {
    var json = (function () { 
        var json = null; 
        $.ajax({ 
            'dataType': "json",
            'url': "/data/supplier_branches/",                  
            'success': function (data) {
                json = data;                     
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data, ["title","info","lat","lng"], 4));          
             }
        });
        return json;
    })();

    for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {            
        latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);

        var data = json[i];

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,                    
                title: data.info,
                map: map                  
            });
            infoBranch(map, marker, data);        
        }
}
```

My code is returning the json data but not using it as markers. What is the fault?

Entire map code:

```
function initialize() {

    var latitude = -23.92175976307374,
        longitude = 24.120724868774414,
        center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
        mapOptions = {
                center: center,
                zoom: 5,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_branches"), mapOptions);

        setMarkers(center, map);

        function setMarkers(center, map) {
        var json = (function () { 
            var json = null; 
            $.ajax({ 
                'dataType': "json",
                'url': "/data/supplier_branches/",                  
                'success': function (data) {
                    json = data;                     
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, ["title","info","lat","lng"], 4));          
                 }
            });
            return json;
        })();

        for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {            
            latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);

            var data = json[i];

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng,                    
                    title: data.info,
                    map: map                  
                });
                infoBranch(map, marker, data);        
            }
    }

         function infoBranch(map, marker, data) {
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        // Attaching a click event to the current marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
            infoWindow.setContent(data.title+data.info);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });

         // Creating a closure to retain the correct data 
        // Note how I pass the current data in the loop into the closure (marker, data)
        (function(marker, data) {
          // Attaching a click event to the current marker
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
            infoWindow.setContent(data.content);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        })(marker, data);
    }

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Console error in Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null branches_maps.js:30
setMarkers branches_maps.js:30
initialize
```

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax is asynchronous, so json is undefined when you start that for loop. Stick your for loop inside your $.ajax callback function.

Comment: Stuck it in `'success': function (data){` and its no longer giving me `Uncaught TypeError` but alas...no markers.

Comment: is the console.log in your callback occurring? In other words, is the success function firing?